# In month forecast in power bi

Tags: powerbi

I have date wise card turn over data for perticulare month.

Date            cardturnover

2022-01-01  34345

2022-01-02  45346

2022-01-03  31267

2022-02-04  34590

2022-02-05  37812

I want to forecast what will the card turnover values for the remaing days of the month or what will be the forcast value for the next 7 days.basically how to genrate in month forcast in power bi.Please help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I just want forecast what would be my sales for the remaining days of a month, using dax formula or measure in power bi.